# How to solve Request to access cookie or storage was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled

Tags: cookies, content-security-policy

I am using Content security Policy and google adsense on my website [www.iusefaith.com](https://www.iusefaith.com/index-en) . My adsense is not displaying and the error message i get in firefox inspector is

> Request to access cookie or storage on
>   “https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=www.iusefaith.com”
>   was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is
>   enabled.

With Chrome I get the following error

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at  was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at  and

Meanwhile I have allowed Google in my content security policy

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  https://code.jquery.com https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com  *.reftagger.com *.fastly.net *.facebook.com *.youtube.com *.googlesyndication.com *.googleapis.com  *.google-analytics.com *.googletagservices.com *.google.com.gh *.google.com *.doubleclick.net *.vimeo.com *.cloudflare.com *.cloudinary.com *.bootstrapcdn.com; img-src * data:; frame-src *;  ">
```

As a result I only get google adsense on my home page and not on the other pages. How to fix it and **enable google adsense to be displayed without Request to access cookie or storage was blocked on all pages ?**

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue with Google Analytics. In FF console: `Request to access cookie or storage on “https://stats.g.doubleclick.net/r/collect?v=1&aip=1&t=dc&_r=…&_gid=569102...843974” was blocked because it came from a tracker and content blocking is enabled.`

Comment: @MattMcCarthy , anyone find solution for that ???

Comment: @DevangHingu For me, it was the Duck Duck Go extension blocking trackers—disabling it on my site fixed the issue. YMMV.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy but it's client side solution. right now **firefox** blocking google adsense `JS`. if anything solution from server(website) side. then it would be a great.

Comment: My solution was client side. It was a FF browser extension causing the issue for me, and had nothing to do with the server. I am just providing what helped for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is outlined clearly in [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Storage_Access_Policy/Errors/CookieBlockedTracker):

> A request to access cookies or storage was blocked because the browser
> identified it as coming from a tracker and content blocking is
> enabled.
>
> The permission can be changed or removed by:
>
> ```
> Going to Preferences > Content Blocking and either
>     adding an exception with the Manage Exceptions… button
>     choosing the Custom Content Blocking and unchecking the Tracker checkbox
> ```
>
> If the blocked resource doesn't need authentication, you can fix the
> warning message by adding a crossorigin="anonymous" attribute to the
> relevant element.

Details of the `crossorigin` attribute can be seen on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin):

> The crossorigin attribute, valid on the `<audio>`, `<img>`, `<link>`,
> `<script>`, and `<video>` elements, provides support for CORS, defining
> how the element handles cross-origin requests, thereby enabling the
> configuration of the CORS requests for the element's fetched data.
> Depending on the element, the attribute can be a CORS settings
> attribute.
>
> The crossorigin content attribute on media elements is a CORS settings
> attribute.
>
> These attributes are enumerated, and have the following possible
> values:
>
> **anonymous**
>
> Request uses CORS headers and credentials flag is set to 'same-origin'. There is no exchange of user credentials via cookies,
> client-side SSL certificates or HTTP authentication, unless
> destination is the same origin.

> **use-credentials**
>
> Request uses CORS headers, credentials flag is set to 'include' and user credentials are always included.

> **""**
>
> Setting the attribute name to an empty value, like crossorigin or crossorigin="", is the same as anonymous.
>
> An invalid keyword and an empty string will be handled as the
> anonymous keyword.
>
> By default (that is, when the attribute is not specified), CORS is not
> used at all. The user agent will not ask for permission for full
> access to the resource and in the case of a cross-origin request,
> certain limitations will be applied based on the type of element
> concerned: